# How to make a command require RCON login

Tags: pawn, sa-mp

How can I make a command require the player to be logged in via RCON in order to execute it? I wish to do this for security reasons.

Comment: This seems to be about an API implemented in PAWN. OP, can you edit your title to specify the API? (I'm guessing it's one of these: San Andreas Multiplayer mod, Half-Life mod, AMX Mod X and Source Engine based SourceMod)

Comment: @Stijn is right, OP. My code below will only work if you are using the San Andreas Multiplayer mod API

Comment: Sorry for inconveniences, I am using samp mod

Comment: James monger your code was correctly and fixed my script

Comment: @Stijn in future I will be using the sa-mp for any of sa-mp questions I post

Comment: @Clove Please do, I've just made the tag as it didn't exist yet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `IsPlayerAdmin(playerid)` will return 1 if the player is logged in via RCON and 0 if the player isn't. To use this for a command, go into the command body and add an if-statement around the part of the command you wish to protect. For example:

```
if(IsPlayerAdmin(playerid))
{
    //do stuff here
}
else
{
    //do nothing, explain security settings to user
}
```